# htaccess Redirect if Contains String WIth Slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^forum/profile$
RewriteRule http://example.com/example.htm? [L,R=301]
```

If the URL contains "forum/profile" I need it to redirect.

What am I doing wrong? I don't need to escape the forward flash do I?

Comment: You have omitted the second argument in your RewriteRule directive.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the ^ and $ operators? These operators means that you want match a string that must have the exact forum/profile on the entire string.

eg:

```
var query_string = forum/profile/something-here
var matches = string.match(^forum/profile$, string) // false because you have string before and after you pattern.
```

Also, you should check what exactly is given on QUERY_STRING.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the forward slash before the file name.
 Eg;
"/forum/profile.php"
Or use "/?" Before you use "$"
You need to use an absolute path.
Hope this answered your question.